# How to override Bootstrap styles in Meteor?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using twbs bootstrap 3.3.6 with Meteor and trying to style a `<fieldset>`.

However when I use the Chrome inspector it says that the style is coming from bootstrap.css even though I have tried using class-specific and id-specific css.

My style sheet is in the application root, as suggested by some answers.

I'm very new to meteor and css so I could be making a novice error.

Otherwise, what's the best practice to override bootstrap css settings?

Comment: Show us some code, some html layout, some styles.

Comment: Could you paste some code? So, it will be clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you want to override the css you should put your css file after all of the other files like the bootstrap css because css starts from top to bottom so the bottom lines are the ones that will be executed, example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your-css.css" />
```

Also you can add `!important` at the end of every css line to give that style the top priority no matter of the line index, example:

```
.someclass {
    color: red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the specific property on the same class in your css...

```
.btn {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

...create an inheritance map so that it only applies to the element inside another specific element...

```
div.classForSpecificContainer btn {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

or specify your own class and add it to the element in question

```
myOverrideClass {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

The.. *important* part is that you use `!important;` to prevent Bootstrap from overriding it. That will generally solve the problem even if the CSS files load in the incorrect order, but not always. I have made a habit of prefixing my CSS files in the same folder with `z-` to make sure they get loaded last if I'm using something like Meteor that merges and compresses the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem in Meteor because of the way their build injects the merged stylesheet into the top of the html `<header>` instead of the bottom. There is a [merged PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9657) that looks like it will be available in 1.6.2 that allows you to put a  pseudo tag anywhere in the `<head>` you want the merged css injected.

Example: proposed availability in 1.6.2 - [PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9657) already merged

```
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='some-cdn.bootstrap.css'/>
    <meteor-bundled-css/>
</head>
```

That will work once the merged PR is included in the next build.

Until then...

SOLUTION 1: If you're using the bootstrap LESS or SCSS files, you can just import it into your `client/main.less` or `client/main.scss` file and then import your override file after this. It looks like you're using pre=compiled css though, so move to SOLUTION 3.

SOLUTION 2: Use !important on the end of your lines... *BAD* not recommended practice. If you use important you break the cascade.

SOLUTION 3: Put you third-party library overrides files in your public folder and manually `<link>` it below the bootstrap `<link>` in your head. *I suggest this for now*.